# Database design for optional discount on food items of a restaurant

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have to design a database for a restaurant chain.

The situation is as follows - The customer gets either Item A free OR Item B free (not both), when he purchases Item C.
 Following are the two tables in my DB.
 [image]

For the above example, I will insert an entry for Item C in the HappyHour_Menu_Trans that will generate a new HappyHourMenuTransId.
Using this HappyHourMenuTransId, I will insert two entries in the HappyHour_Menu_Subsequent Table.

**Now what about the optional part?**

I can think of adding a column 'Condition' in which I will put value 'OR' for both entries. This OR will tell me that I can choose only one option.

If I put value 'AND', it will tell me that I will get discounts on both the items.

This solution is fine for me till now, but my senior wants me to avoid using string. I can use a checkbox (that's not the problem!).

**The Tricky parts starts from here -**

Lets suppose the discount is like this - Buy Item A, and you will get either both (Item B + Item C) free, OR only (Item D + Item E) free.

Now according to my current system I will insert four entries; but how will I know the exact logic from the tables(which two items make a pair?).

Comment: Do you have any experience designing databases? If not, I would highly recommend picking up a book on it. It seems like you're creating the database *around* the application, versus creating the application *around* the database.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Sir I am afraid I dont understand. I am creating the database around the application. If you are saying that this is not the right approach, then can you please suggest me a book.

Comment: Data-Driven Design which puts the DB design first is preferred by those of us who design databases for a living, but it is far from the only valid approach.  There are many valid application-driven design methodologies that put the client-side application design first and then require us DB developers to come up with a database design to support it.

Comment: You may want/need to put some kind of complexity limit on the possible discounts and their structures.  It is easy enough to design table(s) to support your discounting structure with nearly unlimited complexity.  Designing the queries to return it all is slightly harder.  But writing the code to consume this information, figure our the logical implications and then apply it all to the orders is quite a bit harder, especially so the more complicated these discounts can potentially be.

Answer (score 0):

I need clarification on the following statement you made.

*"Buy Item A, and you will get either both (Item B + Item C) free, OR only (Item D + Item E) free."*

**Is it only Item D or Item E?**

Initially I was thinking this could be solved with some type of referential integrity.

A discount table has the following entries.

```
(Purchase Item, Free Item)
(A, B)
(A, C)
```

Create a foreign key relationship between the [HappyHour_Menu_Subsequent] table and these two columns.  However, this assumes a 1-to-1 relationship.  If you start bundling items, 1-to-1 or 1-to-x, this solution will fail.

Given the fact that the business logic might change, there are two solutions that come to mind.

1 - I would use an INSERT or UPDATE trigger to enforce your business logic if the application does direct inserts and updates to the tables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRG_ENFORCE_MY_HAPPY_HOUR_DEALS] 
    ON [HappyHour_Menu_Subsequent]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

-- put your logic here
IF (Violation) 
    RAISERROR();

END
```

The Violation is just a place holder.  You will have to look at the inserted and deleted tables to retrieve the purchased item and free item.  Make sure the combination meets your business rules.

Have the front end handle the error if the logic is violated.

2 - If you use stored procedures to perform INSERTS or UPDATES, add the business logic in that code.

Comment: Buy Item A, and you will get either both (Item B + Item C) free, OR only (Item D + Item E) free.
It means that if you buy A then you can get A,B,C (B,C free) or A,D,E (D,E free)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, create another table called Group_Item, this table will hold the item as a pair, for your example we will have two rows, one row contains Item (B + C) and one row contains Item ( D + E). If implement like this, you can enhance the item length or reduce in pair, for example (B + C + D) or (C + F).

In case if not a pair just a single item like you said above:

> The customer gets either Item A free OR Item B free

We will have two rows, one row contains Item A only and another row contains Item B only